# Difference between re_formula and vc_formula in statsmodel formula api

Tags: python, statsmodels, mixed-models

In the documentation, both re_formula and vc_formula are said to describe variance structure of the model. How are they different?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.